# Pegando o conteudo de uma variavel JS em um metodo asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma function que pega os values do meus inputs, e quero levar os valores da variavel para meu metodo realizar o insert. Alguem tem alguma dica de como fazer isso?

```
function insert_veiculo() {
  var placa = $("#placa").val();
  var quilometragem = $("#quilometragem").val();
  var cor = $("#cor").val();
  var tipo = $("#tipo").val();
  var chassi = $("#chassi").val();
  var ano = $("#ano").val();
  var modelo = $("#modelo").val();
}
```

Na function a cima, pego todo os values dos meus inputs

Answer (score 2):

Podes utilizar o `$.getJSON` para fazer o que pretendes:

```
$.getJSON("/nomeTeuController/nomeTuaFuncao", { placa : placa, quilometragem : quilometragem, cor: cor, tipo : tipo, chassi : chassi, ano : ano, modelo :modelo }
   , function (result) {
       alert("Dados Gravados");
   });
```

E no teu controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult nomeTuaFuncao(string placa, decimal quilometragem, string cor, string tipo, string chassi, int ano, string modelo)
{
    try
    {
        var novoElemento = new Veiculo();
        novoElemento.placa = placa;
        novoElemento.quilometragem = quilometragem;
        novoElemento.cor = cor;
        novoElemento.tipo = tipo;
        novoElemento.chassi = chassi;
        novoElemento.ano = ano;
        novoElemento.modelo = modelo;
        db.Veiculo.add(novoElemento);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json("Dados Gravados", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "Erro", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: E como faço pra tratar esses dado no meu dal?

Meu DAL: http://i.imgur.com/QetspNN.png

Comment: O que está no deu DAL? Uma base de dados externa? Depende sempre da base de dados que é, e como se inserem la os dados...

Comment: Minha ideia seria, receber no meu método os values das variaveis JS e  de la, mandar pro meu DAL.

Comment: Mas isso já é uma questão diferente da publicada... Para receberes os values já tens aí a solução

Comment: desculpe meu amadorismo. É porque estou uma app para faculdade, e está sendo meu primo contato com asp.net e c# e me deparei com esse pequeno "problema".

Comment: Não há problema. Como te disse, já tens a solução para passar os values para o controller, agora para gravar no teu DAL vai depender de base de dados para base de dados que uses...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17375/discussion-between-paulo-vinicius-matos-and-cesarmiguel).